# How can I minimize the RAM consumption in my flutter application with firebase firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have an application made with Flutter that connects to the Firebase Firestore and reads a considerable amount of documents. Each time the user moves between the views of the application and returns to the view where these documents are displayed, the use of RAM space is greater. What I have in my code is a StreamBuilder that calls the collection every time the view is loaded. My question is: **Is there a way to minimize the use of RAM each time that view is loaded?**, since this application crashes every time it reaches its limit in RAM memory space on devices with little RAM memory. Please I need help with this!.This is my StreamBuilder code:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: this.rolUsuario != 'Digitador'
        ? this
            .fs
            .collection('Encuestas')
            .where('OrganizacionPerteneciente',
                isEqualTo: this.organizacionPerteneciente)
            .orderBy('FechaCreacion', descending: true)
            .snapshots()
        : this
            .fs
            .collection('Encuestas')
            .where('OrganizacionPerteneciente',
                isEqualTo: this.organizacionPerteneciente)
            .where('Asignada', arrayContains: this.uID.toString())
            .orderBy('FechaCreacion', descending: true)
            .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        default:
          this.encuestas = new List<Encuesta>();
          snapshot.data.documents.forEach((encuesta) {
            this.encuestas.add(Encuesta.parse(encuesta.data));
          });

          return snapshot.data.documents.length == 0
              ? Center(
                  child: Text(
                    this.rolUsuario != 'Digitador'
                        ? 'Aún no se han creado encuestas en la plataforma.\nPara agregar nuevas encuestas ve a https://surveyflow.tk desde un computador.'
                        : 'Aún no tienes asignada ninguna encuesta para rellenar.',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                    color: Colors.blueGrey[100],
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                    child: ListTile(
                      selected: false,
                      title: Text(
                        snapshot.data.documents[index]['Nombre'],
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      dense: true,
                      subtitle: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text: snapshot.data.documents[index]
                                    ['Descripcion'] +
                                '\n',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.blueGrey,
                            ),
                            children: <TextSpan>[
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: 'Fecha de Creación: ' +
                                      imprimirFecha(
                                        snapshot.data.documents[index]
                                            ['FechaCreacion'],
                                      ),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  )),
                            ]),
                      ),
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        child: Text(snapshot
                            .data.documents[index]['Encuestados']
                            .toString()),
                      ),
                      isThreeLine: false,
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => RellenarEncuestaView(
                              encuestaEditar: Encuesta.parse(
                                  snapshot.data.documents[index]),
                              isAndroid: this.widget.isAndroid,
                              tipoEdicion: 'nuevo',
                              authInstance: this.widget.authInstance,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                );
      }
    },
  ),
```

Comment: As a point of feedback on the question - the frequent use of bold made it difficult for me to read.  Consider toning it down, separating thoughts into paragraphs.  There's no need to bold the names of APIs, technologies, and products.

Comment: @DougStevenson done!.

Comment: @EdycarReyes have you found a solution?